# img and text (with ellipsis) in the same line - CENTERED

Tags: html, css, center, ellipsis

Here is a code of example:
  [problem code example](http://codepen.io/2PR/pen/LVdjbE)
 I have a code where below conditions must be fulfilled:
1) img and text in the same line
2) text with ellipsis (so text length do not cause moving it to next line)
3) both img and text centered in parent

First condition is easy: `img{float:left;}`

Same with the second one:

```
longName{ 
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display:block;}
```

But third one is a real pain for me. If I leave it as it is only text will center, while img stays on left (not visible with long names) - third element in example. 
Any change I try:
moves text to next line 
or 
destroy ellipsis effect 
or 
goes off parent borders.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily sort this out with the flex model.

```
.img-circle {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
 }
```

[fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMXGG)

Comment: image in the middle one is now smaller than it should be it was 20 X 20 now it is 16.1563 X 20. Can you please tell me how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

```
li{
  width:15%;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#img1{
   /*float:left;*/vertical-align: inherit;
} 

#longName{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display:inline-block; max-width:175px;
}

#parent4{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpoEZW)**

Comment: Thank you, but it moves the middle one text (long one) to next line. There's alredy a good answer from GCyrillus.